# Google Sheets Add-On - Show Side Bar Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

We recently published a google sheet add-on(Reviewed and approved by Google OAuthTeam & Workspace Team).

The add-on upon user action from a menu item - fetches data from a REST API. When the response from the REST API is 200 OK - launches the side bar.

This seems to be working at the time of development. But NOT working as add-on. The error that I see in the cloud logs is as follows.

> Exception: You do not have access to perform that action. Please ask
> the owner of this item to grant access to you.

```
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('dashboard').evaluate()
   .setTitle("Dashboard").setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

    var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    ss.showSidebar(html);
```

> It fails in the line ss.showSidebar(html);

> "Test Deployment" as "Installed for current user", "Enabled in current
> document", "Installed and Enabled" DID NOT throw any errors

I have seen an issue of similar kind reported in Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69238694#comment7) but that's pretty old. So not sure if that's still valid.

Any help/guidance on this subject would be very much appreciated.

> - This add-on is working on a Windows machine/Chrome browser
> - This add-on is working on a MacOS Catalina/Chrome browser
> - This add-on is NOT WORKING on a MacOS Monterey M1 Chip/Chrome browser
> - This add-on is working on a MacOS Monterey M1 Chip/Safari Browser with a strange behavoiur - Every Google Script that you call opens a new tab on the browser

Comment: Please provide HTML so we can generate it for ourselves

Comment: @Cooper - The HTML is well formed and seems to working everywhere except in the published add-on :-) It has also few lines of apple script embedded in it. here's the file --> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xROUkEzi9eaLE9to42IfQqI3qUAEl5EwLnSmX2ACyOY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Cooper - excuse the typos. I meant "google app" script in my above response.. NOT "apple" script